# The friendly cryptic where nobody has to die!

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

**Warning**: This puzzle may contain spoilers about *Undertale* and its plot. Please don't proceed if you don't want to be spoiled, since nothing will be in hide tags!

---

*Undertale* was released for the Switch this year, and *Deltarune* was released recently too! This puzzle will revisit the *Undertale* universe, with all of its zany characters and morally challenging plot routes—as we know, there's three general routes you can take in *Undertale*: the Pacifist Route, the Genocide Route, and the Neutral Route. Each of the clues in this puzzle has chosen to follow exactly one of those routes, but when I played the game, it seems I didn't have much of a choice.

**(1)** The 20 clues on the **Pacifist Route** have each made friends with an *Undertale* character, with 4 clues for each of the 5 characters. For each of these clues, taking the *n*-th letter from the front of the clue, where *n* is the number associated with the character below, will tell you why I couldn't follow these clues along the Pacifist Route.

1. **Toriel** thinks that cryptic clues are too hard, so she's added an extra definition to each of them to try to hint them better.
2. **Papyrus**: NYEH-HEH-HEH!! I'VE TURNED ALL MY ENTRIES BLUE!!
3. **Undyne**'s been throwing her spears in all directions, especially unconventional ones, and she might have thrown some entries too.
4. **Alphys**, as addicted to social media as always, can only find the time to transmit the clues over the phone.
5. **Asgore** still feels bad about the time he broke the SPARE button, so he's added SPARE letters to one word in each of his clues. They might have gotten a bit messy in the process, though.

**(2)** Instead, I followed the **Genocide Route**, along with 21 clues: each of them has had a visit from Sans, who's up to his practical jokes, as always. Each clue's wordplay half produces a string that is one letter longer than what its definition half defines (and that may or may not be a word). The word defined by the definition half, which should be entered, is thus this string, *sans* a character (ha!). Taking these extra characters, in clue order, will tell you the equally bad line I delivered once I defeated Sans.

**(3)** Finally, the remaining 17 clues in the puzzle followed the **Neutral Route**. They function as normal clues.

**(4)** *Undertale* is all about exploring where the line between right and wrong or good and evil lies, in order to find out what's truly important: thusly, highlight each cell on the grid which lies on the intersection between a Pacifist and Genocide entry. The highlighted letters, in clue order, will spell out the wordplay half of a final cryptic clue, which will show what's truly important in *Undertale*, depending on which route you've chosen!

[image: it's a grid!]

**Across**
**1** Servant's failure to gain river land
**6** MBA, for example, hosts empty time for everyone (hyph.)
**11** Current, fashionable model entering car
**12** Attempt to take in love for wait system
**13** Character with speech impediment to go back in time by infinitesimal amount
**14** Magician Geller, formerly known as "Waste Material"
**15** POOCH GROOVE appears in odd meta
**17** Informally tell on in Australia home, heading out back
**18** Recess time's right to follow clubs
**20** Leading man journalist gazed at
**22** Japanese hot spring's on mountain base, filled with brine
**24** Professor with grand shadow
**25** Selected column to showcase ancient architecture, ultimately
**28** Ruins chocolate bar brand
**30** Notes sea-scaper of legal importance
**31** Employment of wise man after unemployment starts
**35** Grants revolutionary sight to follow augur regularly
**37** Sorcerers trap soldier
**39** Establish group to chase thieves on the inside
**40** Defeat—also, behead—soldiers from both sides
**41** Mats rearranged to cover Regina's fly sting
**42** Dynamic, pivotal role, but losing at club
**45** In the middle of ammonia derivant
**46** Thieves air gun, breaking into Sorre composition
**47** "Plane": the composition's 23 by 28 inches
**48** One in front of the other: time and—

**Down**
**1** Vis-a-vis being eaten by leopards: man's fear
**2** Hack advertising by the Ocean State
**3** Spike drink with drugs, essentially, to be set up with thirst
**4** Covered in gold—"shame!", we hear
**5** Artist Schieren, of old Tokyo
**6** Noble gas returning zero effects, briefly
**7** Upset, primarily, engaged in cold complaint to duelist Aaron
**8** Morale raised by excursions
**9** Spaces containing negative ages
**10** Color of flag on the radio
**12** Crazy rant about Vietnamese dynasty
**15** "Heartbreak! Paupers imprisoned by woman," Tom cries
**16** "Introduction to Animation" to follow "Body Art Brief" later
**17** British military award daring soldiers obtained, primarily (abbr.)
**19** Outcomes of Erin neatly dusting staircases, from tops to bottoms
**21** Wear clothing, heading out
**22** Scored zero—it can be relied on (hyph.)
**23** Blunt blades were sharp once, too; edge softens, in the end
**24** Raffle to give away a, er, musical instrument
**26** Currency related to nervous system
**27** Plastered and drunk, initially, rush to welcome ship
**29** That head covering!
**32** A profit, once more
**33** Belt brief dirge out
**34** Prohibitionist carrying, initially, expensive champagne to wrap
**36** Twitch's Spring Sale market starts
**38** Working plan to support personae: 1,000 rounds
**39** Auditor's pen is cause of sore eyes
**40** Tag, with front scratched off, for first murder victim
**41** Blue's Clues ending with commercial
**43** In the spotlight: Psy's latest books
**44** Before queen and her heart

Comment: In the description of the Genocide Route, do you mean that the wordplay produces a string 1 letter longer than *the definition*, or 1 letter longer than *what the definition defines*? (The former is what the rubric says; the latter seems a priori more likely.)

Comment: @Gareth: 1 letter longer than what the definition defines, my bad! I'll go edit that.

Comment: Just played undertale, so perfect timing for me to.. uh, not solve this as fast as someone else.  Looks fun -- although, there seems to be a mettaton shaped hole in this mettaton shaped puzzle.

Comment: Would you care to clarify whether the answers entered on the Genocide Route are always words? (And, just to check: there is no reason why the answer entered should be the same as the result of the definition, right? The wordplay is defined-word + 1 letter and is answer + 1 letter, but the defined-word and the answer could be different?)

Comment: (Where "word" means "thing that wouldn't be out of place as a solution in a normal cryptic crossword"; obviously it might be a person's name or something like that, rather than a dictionary word.)

Comment: (So far, in the cases I'm surest about it looks as if the answer entered _is_ always the same as the definition result. But the rubric strongly suggests otherwise.)

Comment: 48a is hilarious, by the way.

Comment: I know this is already solved, but updated the Genocide Route mechanic explanation again to clarify!

Comment: "and Deltarune was released recently too!" - well, the demo, anyway. Hopefully the full game will be released too one day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the filled grid:

> [image]

Explanation of Pacifist transformations:

> Toriel's clues include one wordplay portion, and two distinct definition portions, all for the same word.
>  Answers to Papyrus' clues can become 'blue' in some manner. Three times, the answers can be directly associated to 'red', and have 'blue' counterparts; the fourth entry has a related word that is synonymous with 'blue'.
>  Answers to Undyne's clues are entered in reverse in their slots.
>  Alphys' clues include one word that has been replaced by a homophone.
>  Asgore's clues include one word that has been anagrammed with the additional letters {S,P,A,R,E}.

Clues, answers, and explanations:
**ACROSS**

**1.** Servant's failure to gain river land

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is T.
>  **DRUDGE** = servant; R [river] in DUD [failure], plus GET [land]

**6.** MBA, for example, hosts empty time for everyone (hyph.)

> This is a Papyrus clue. "Blue" also means risque or obscene, so G-RATED becomes the entry **X-RATED**.
>  **G-RATED** = for everyone; T__E [empty time] in GRAD [MBA, for example]

**11.** Current, fashionable model entering car

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is H.
>  **RIPTIDE** = current; HIP [fashionable] and T [model, as in Ford Model T] inside RIDE [car]

**12.** Attempt to take in love for wait system

> This is an Alphys clue. The word 'wait' should actually be 'weight' in the clue.
>  **TROY** = weight system; O [love, as in 0 in tennis] inside TRY [attempt]

**13.** Character with speech impediment to go back in time by infinitesimal amount

> This is a Toriel clue.
>  **EPSILON** = character (Greek letter) AND infinitesimal amount (common variable in math for amounts that shrink to zero); LISP [speech impediment] reversed and inside [get back in] EON [time]

**14.** Magician Geller, formerly known as "Waste Material"

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is E.
>  **URINE** = waste material; URI [magician Geller] and NEE [formerly known as]

**15.** POOCH GROOVE appears in odd meta

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is R.
>  **MUTT** = pooch; RUT [groove] in M_T_ [odd (letters of) "meta"]

**17.** Informally tell on in Australia home, heading out back

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is E.
>  **DOB** = informally tell on, in Australia; ABODE [home] with no first letter A [heading out] and reversed [back]

**19.** Recess time's right to follow clubs

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is S.
>  **APSE** = recess; _E [time's right(most letter)] following SAPS [clubs]

**20.** Leading man journalist gazed at

> This is an Undyne clue.
>  **STARED** = gazed at; STAR [leading man] plus ED. [journalist (editor)]

**22.** Japanese hot spring's on mountain base, filled with brine

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is A.
>  **ONSEN** = Japanese hot spring; ON [on] plus _N [mountain base (last letter)] containing SEA [brine]

**24.** Professor with grand shadow

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is N.
>  **DOG** = shadow, as in follow; DON [professor] plus G [grand]

**25.** Selected column to showcase ancient architecture, ultimately

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is E.
>  **OPTED** = selected; OP.ED. [column] containing _T _E [ancient architecture, ultimately (last letters)]

**28.** Ruins chocolate bar brand

> This is a Papyrus clue. MARS is the Red Planet, so the entry is the Blue Planet: **EARTH**.
>  **MARS** = ruins AND chocolate bar brand

**30.** Notes sea-scaper of legal importance

> This is an Asgore clue. The word 'sea-scaper' should actually be 'case' in the clue.
>  **RES** = notes (as in do-re-mi) AND case of legal importance (Latin for thing, common in legal terminology)

**31.** Employment of wise man after unemployment starts

> This is a Neutral clue.
>  **USAGE** = employment; SAGE [wise man] after U_ [unemployment start(ing letter)]

**35.** Grants revolutionary sight to follow augur regularly

> This is a Neutral clue.
>  **AGREES** = grants; SEE backwards [revolutionary sight] after A_G_R [augur regularly (every other letter)]

**37.** Sorcerers trap soldier

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is W.
>  **MAGI** = sorcerers; MAW [trap, as in mouth] plus G.I. [soldier]

**39.** Establish group to chase thieves on the inside

> This is a Toriel clue.
>  **SET** = establish AND group; found hidden inside "cha**SE T**hieves"

**40.** Defeat—also, behead—soldiers from both sides

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is S.
>  **LOSS** = defeat; _LSO [also, behead] and S_S [soldiers from both sides (first and last letters)]

**41.** Mats rearranged to cover Regina's fly sting

> This is a Toriel clue.
>  **SMART** = fly (as in fashionable) AND sting (as in ache); SMAT* [mats rearranged] containing R [Regina]

**42.** Dynamic, pivotal role, but losing at club

> This is a Papyrus clue. Liverpool F.C. is nicknamed 'The Reds', so the entry is the club nicknamed 'The Blues', which is **CHELSEA**.
>  **LIVERPOOL** = club, as in football; LIVERPOOLAT* [dynamic (anagram) "pivotal role"] without the AT [losing at]

**45.** In the middle of ammonia derivant

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is E.
>  **AMID** = in the middle of; AMIDE [ammonia derivant]

**46.** Thieves air gun, breaking into Sorre composition

> This is a Neutral clue.
>  **ROBBERS** = thieves; BB [air gun] inside ROERS* ["sorre" composition (anagram)]

**47.** "Plane": the composition's 23 by 28 inches

> This is a Papyrus clue. The elephant is the mascot animal for the Republicans (Red) in the USA, so the entry is the mascot animal for the Democrats (Blue) in the USA, which is the **DONKEY**.
>  **ELEPHANT** = 23 by 28 inches, [as a sheet size](https://www.papersizes.org/old-english-uncut.htm); ELEPHANT* ["plane the" composition (anagram)]

**48.** One in front of the other: time and—

> This is a Neutral clue.
>  **TANDEM** = one in front of the other; T [time] plus AND [and] plus EM [— (a typographic unit of length)]

**DOWN**

**1.** Vis-a-vis being eaten by leopards: man's fear

> This is an Asgore clue. The word 'leopards' should actually be 'old' in the clue.
>  **DREAD** = fear; RE: [vis-a-vis] inside DAD [old man]

**2.** Hack advertising by the Ocean State

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is R.
>  **RIP** = hack; P.R. [advertising] after R.I. [Ocean State]

**3.** Spike drink with drugs, essentially, to be set up with thirst

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is I.
>  **UPSURGE** = spike; SIP [drink] plus *U* [drugs, essentially (central letter)], reversed [set up], plus URGE [thirst]

**4.** Covered in gold—"shame!", we hear

> This is a Neutral clue.
>  **GILT** = covered in gold; homophone [we hear] of GUILT [shame]

**5.** Artist Schieren, of old Tokyo

> This is an Alphys clue. The word "Schieren" should actually be "Sheeran" in the clue.
>  **EDO** = (old) Tokyo; ED [artist Sheeran] plus O [old]

**6.** Noble gas returning zero effects, briefly

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is F.
>  **XENON** = noble gas; NONE FX [zero effects, briefly] reversed [returning]

**7.** Upset, primarily, engaged in cold complaint to duelist Aaron

> This is an Undyne clue.
>  **BURR** = duelist Aaron; U_ [upset, primarily (first letter)] in BRR [cold complaint]

**8.** Morale raised by excursions

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is I.
>  **TRIPS** = excursions; reversal [raised] of SPIRIT [morale]

**9.** Spaces containing negative ages

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is N.
>  **EONS** = ages; ENS [spaces (typographic)] containing NO [negative]

**10.** Color of flag on the radio

> This is a Neutral clue.
>  **DYE** = color; homophone [on the radio] of DIE [flag, as in decline/fade]

**12.** Crazy rant about Vietnamese dynasty

> This is a Neutral clue.
>  **TRAN** = Vietnamese dynasty; TRAN* [crazy (anagram) "rant"]

**15.** "Heartbreak! Paupers imprisoned by woman," Tom cries

> This is an Asgore clue. The word 'Paupers' should actually be 'up' in the clue.
>  **MEOWS** = Tom (as in male cat) cries; WOE [heartbreak] reversed [up] inside MS. [woman]

**16.** "Introduction to Animation" to follow "Body Art Brief" later

> This is a Neutral clue.
>  **TA-TA** = brief "Later!"; A_ [introduction (first letter) to animation] following TAT [body art]

**17.** British military award daring soldiers obtained, primarily (abbr.)

> This is a Neutral clue.
>  **DSO** = British military award (Distinguished Service Order); initials [primarily] of "daring soldiers obtained"

**19.** Outcomes of Erin neatly dusting staircases, from tops to bottoms

> This is a Toriel clue.
>  **ENDS** = outcomes AND bottoms; initials [tops] of "Erin neatly dusting staircases"

**21.** Wear clothing, heading out

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is T.
>  **TIRE** = wear; ATTIRE [clothing] without the first letter A [heading out]

**22.** Scored zero—it can be relied on (hyph.)

> This is an Undyne clue.
>  **GO-TO** = it can be relied on; GOT 0 [scored zero]

**23.** Blunt blades were sharp once, too; edge softens, in the end

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is O.
>  **EPEES** = blunt blades; final letters [in the end] of "were sharp once too edge softens"

**24.** Raffle to give away a, er, musical instrument

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is W.
>  **DRUM** = musical instrument; DRAW [raffle] without the A [give away a], plus UM [er (hesitation)]

**26.** Currency related to nervous system

> This is a Genocide clue. The extra letter is N.
>  **EURO** = currency; NEURO [related to nervous system]

**27.** Plastered and drunk, initially, rush to welcome ship

> This is a Neutral clue.
>  **DRESSED** = plastered; D_ [drunk, initially], plus REED [rush (plant)] containing S.S. [ship]

**29.** That head covering!

> This is a Neutral clue.
>  **HAT** = head covering &lit. (the entire clue is both definition and wordplay); the first letter [head] of "that" covers the remaining part "hat"

**32.** A profit, once more

> This is a Neutral clue.
>  **AGAIN** = once more; A GAIN [a profit]

**33.** Belt brief dirge out

> This is a Neutral clue.
>  **GIRD** = belt; DIRG_ [brief (all but last letter) dirge] anagrammed [out]

**34.** Prohibitionist carrying, initially, expensive champagne to wrap

> This is an Alphys clue. The word 'wrap' should actually be 'rap' in the clue.
>  **DECRY** = rap; DRY [prohibitionist] containing E_ C_ [initially, expensive champagne]

**36.** Twitch's Spring Sale market starts

> This is a Neutral clue.
>  **SPASM** = twitch; SPA [(hot) spring] plus S_ M_ ["sale market" starts]

**38.** Working plan to support personae: 1,000 rounds

> This is an Asgore clue. The word 'personae' should actually be 'one' in the clue.
>  **AMMO** = rounds; M.O. [working plan] following A [one] plus M [1,000]

**39.** Auditor's pen is cause of sore eyes

> This is a Neutral clue.
>  **STYE** = cause of sore eyes; homophone [auditor's] of STY [pen]

**40.** Tag, with front scratched off, for first murder victim

> This is an Undyne clue.
>  **ABEL** = first murder victim; LABEL [tag] with no first letter L [front scratched off]

**41.** Blue's Clues ending with commercial

> This is a Neutral clue.
>  **SAD** = blue; _S ["clues" ending] plus AD [commercial]

**43.** In the spotlight: Psy's latest books

> This is an Alphys clue. The word 'Psy' should actually be 'sigh' in the clue.
>  **HOT** = in the spotlight; _H ["sigh"s latest (last letter)] plus OT [books (Old Testament)]

**44.** Before queen and her heart

> This is a Neutral clue.
>  **ERE** = before; ER [queen (Elizabeth, Regina)] plus *E* ["her" heart (central letter)]

---

Why Couldn't I Follow The Pacifist Route:

> **BECAUSE MY LV IS TOO HIGH**
>  Explaining this one gets more spoiler-y into Undertale than I wish. But, yeah, Level 51 is *way* too high.

Post-Sans One Liner:

> **THERE'S A NEW SERIF IN TOWN**
>  Sans (and Papyrus) are named for typefaces (which they aptly use in their text boxes). Specifically, Sans is named for Comic Sans / Comic Sans Serif.

Exploring What's Truly Important:

> The intersection letters spell "DEXTER DROPS NUMBER TO NOTE REALM".
>  This is wordplay for: **DE**X**TER** minus the X [drops number (X=10)], plus **MI** [note] plus **NATION** [realm].
>  So what truly important is **DETERMINATION**, which is definitely an important concept in *Undertale*.

Exploring What's Truly Important (REDUX):

> Level 51 indicated a second part to this clue.
>  The intersection letters spell "DEXTER DROPS NUMBER TO NOTE REALM".
>  This is wordplay for: D**EXTER** minus the D [drops number (D=500)], plus **MI** [note] plus **NATION** [realm].
>  So what truly important is **EXTERMINATION**, which is definitely an important concept in *Undertale*, especially to the sort of person who would go on a Genocide run and use file-editing to reach Level 51 when the actual levels only go up to 20!
>  (ꐦ ಠ皿ಠ )

Answer (score 4):

Grid:

> [image]

Solutions, classifications, words needed to make sense of Papyrus and Asgore clues, and letters obtained from Pacifist and Genocide clues:

> `Across
>  
>   1 DRUDGE  Genocide           T
>   6 X-RATED Pacifist Papyrus B   G-RATED
>  11 RIPTIDE Genocide           H
>  12 TROY    Pacifist Alphys  E   WEIGHT
>  13 EPSILON Pacifist Toriel  C
>  14 URINE   Genocide           E
>  15 MUTT    Genocide           R
>  17 DOB     Genocide           E <-- I don't actually understand this one
>  18 APSE    Genocide           S
>  20 STARED  Pacifist Undyne  A
>  22 ONSEN   Genocide           A
>  24 DOG     Genocide           N
>  25 OPTED   Genocide           E
>  28 EARTH   Pacifist Papyrus U   MARS
>  30 RES     Pacifist Asgore  S
>  31 USAGE   Neutral
>  35 AGREES  Neutral
>  37 MAGI    Genocide           W
>  39 SET     Pacifist Toriel  E
>  40 LOSS    Genocide           S
>  41 SMART   Pacifist Toriel  M
>  42 CHELSEA Pacifist Papyrus Y   LIVERPOOL
>  45 AMID    Genocide           E
>  46 ROBBERS Neutral
>  47 DONKEY  Pacifist Papyrus L   ELEPHANT
>  48 TANDEM  Neutral
>  
>  Down
>  
>   1 DREAD   Pacifist Asgore  V   OLD
>   2 RIP     Genocide           R
>   3 UPSURGE Genocide           I
>   4 GILT    Neutral
>   5 EDO     Pacifist Alphys  I   SHEERAN
>   6 XENON   Genocide           F
>   7 BURR    Pacifist Undyne  S
>   8 TRIPS   Genocide           I
>   9 EONS    Genocide           N
>  10 DYE     Neutral
>  12 TRAN    Neutral
>  15 MEOWS   Pacifist Asgore  T   UP
>  16 TATA    Neutral
>  17 DSO     Neutral
>  19 ENDS    Pacifist Toriel  O
>  21 TIRE    Genocide           T
>  22 GOTO    Pacifist Undyne  O
>  23 EPEES   Genocide           O
>  24 DRUM    Genocide           W
>  26 EURO    Genocide           N
>  27 DRESSED Neutral
>  29 HAT     Neutral
>  32 AGAIN   Neutral
>  33 GIRD    Neutral
>  34 DECRY   Pacifist Alphys  H   RAP
>  36 SPASM   Neutral
>  38 AMMO    Pacifist Asgore  I   ONE
>  39 STYE    Neutral
>  40 ABEL    Pacifist Undyne  G
>  41 SAD     Neutral
>  43 HOT     Pacifist Alphys  H   SIGH
>  44 ERE     Neutral`

Extraction from Pacifist clues:

> `BECAUSE MY LV IS TOO HIGH` (which I believe makes sense in the context of Undertale)

Extraction from Genocide clues:

> `THERE'S A NEW SERIF IN TOWN` (which seems plausible; note that the guy's name is *Sans*)

Extraction from intersections of P and G clues:

> `DEXTER DROPS NUMBER TO NOTE REALM` (which yields DETERMINATION)

[EDITED to add:]

> There's a bit of extra subtlety in that last bit of wordplay, because there are *two* numbers you can drop from DEXTER. One way gets you DETERMINATION, and the other gets you EXTERMINATION. How very appropriate! (Credit where due: I didn't notice this for myself; MPH got it from an edit L51 made to the question after I posted the original version of this answer.)